# Laravel ::all() command only returns 1 record

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, web, eloquent

Hi guys I am trying to get all the records from a table in my database using  `$pools = \App\pool::all();`
The database currently has 3 records in it but only the first record is returned

```
foreach($pools as $pool)
    {return $pool;}

{"poolId":1,"poolName":"TestPool","pAdminId":70,"poolStatus":1,"created_at":"2021-11-17 08:06:57","updated_at":"2021-11-17 08:06:57"}
```

[image: My SQLDB]

This has not been a problem before when using ::all()
The same is true when using

```
$pools = \App\Pool::where('pAdminId',$user->id)->get();
```

The $user->id returns 70, this is also happening for another table of mine Poolmembers, both were created using the php artisan make:model command and rolled back once to change a datatype and then migrated again.

The model for pool looks as follow

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Pool extends Model
{
    //
    protected $primaryKey = 'poolId';
    protected $fillable = ['poolId', 'poolName', 'pAdminId', 'poolStatus'];
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Thank you

Comment: Please share your model

Comment: The model looks as follow for Pool `<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Pool extends Model
{
    //
    
    protected $fillable = ['poolId', 'poolName', 'pAdminId', 'poolStatus'];
}
`

Comment: @armand edit the question with the code, don't put it in the comments

Comment: Just been updated

Comment: set the primary key and check it protected $primaryKey = 'poolId';

Comment: I updated my model to include this but the results remain the same

Comment: You using return inside foreach loop which going to stop execution in the first loop

Comment: This has solved my problem I can see that it is in fact adding all of them. Thank you for the assistance it is appreciated

Comment: @MouradKaroudi put this as an answer and perhaps show an example of the correct way to fix it `:-)`

Comment: I am very new to stancoverflow how to I add this as an answer or should I choose the answer own question and then also put the solution in the answer?

Answer (score 4):

You can get only one return statement in a function so if you put return inside the loop the execution of a function will stop.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.return.php

```
foreach($pools as $pool) {
    echo $pool->poolId;
}
```

if you want to skip or break an iteration in PHP you can use `continue` or `break` inside your loop.

Answer (score 1):

Armand, You are using return in for loop.
Due to which it shows you only a single record because it returns on the first index of the array.
Try this

```
foreach($pools as $pool)
    {
echo $pool->poolId; //it will return id of each record;
}
```